# ¿Cómo mejorar rendimiento?

Tags: php, jquery, html5

Buenas,  estoy realizando una web en la que uso jquery,canvas,php y css. Me veo obligado a usar ubuntu 12 con firefox 50.0b4.  El caso es que al ejecutar animaciones con html5, jquery o canvas, se hace muy lento he incluso en ocasiones se pierde el efecto de animacion y aparecen imagenes de repente.
¿alguna idea para mejorar el rendimiento?,  ¿es posible que se deba a jquery y que si paso todo a php mejore el rendimiento?.

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el código por favor?

Answer (score 0):

jquery y php son dos cosas muy diferentes, jquery se ejecuta del lado del cliente y php del lado del servidor, si las animaciones que estas realizando están muy lentas tal vez sea porque los scripts js pesan mucho o no están optimizados,  trata utilizar el minificado (.min.js), por otro lado si realizas operaciones que solicitan respuesta del servidor y esta lenta esta respuesta, optimiza tu código en php.

Comment: en este caso tanto parte cliente como parte servidor se ejecutan en el mismo equipo, por eso creo que deveria de dar igual que el codigo se interprete en php o jquery. La idea de que el problema puede ser de jquery es por que en la consola de desarrollo de firefox en la parte de network, no me aparece ninguna llamada a php.  En cuanto a rendimiento, ¿es mejor general el codigo html dinamicamente o crearlo todo al inicio de la app y mostrarlo en funcion de las necesidades del usuario?, supongo que uno conllevara mas ram y otro mas cpu.

Comment: Lo recomendable seria que cargue en segundo plano lo que voy solicitando a si no se satura tu servidor